# Which one is better in a CNN, smaller input size or bigger input size followed by larger kernels and strides?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What do you suggest and why?
`AlexNet`, `VGG`, `GoogleNet`, etc use `227/224` input images, and then use large kernels such as `11x11` or `7x7` and drastically decrease the input size, followed by pooling till the input is ~`54x54` and then continue using that.
Why not using `54x54` from the start?
The point here is, It seems to me, the first layer at which down-sampling is carried out, has very little need for such large input.
Feeding a `54x54` image, and then keeping the size intact for the next several layers, provides much more wealth of information compared to getting a large input, to only learn edges and then send a `54x54` image to the immediate next layer for further processings.   to me this seems an un-necessary processing burden.